# Format Date Fields to String in XStream

Tags: java, date, format, xstream

I have a date field, which when converted to xml using [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/), gives time in milliseconds and zone. I just need to convert or format it as `"MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"`. How to do that using XStream? I don't want to change the getters and setters. Thanks.

My class:

```
    public class Datas {
    private String name;
    private Calendar dob;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Calendar getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Calendar dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Datas datas = new Datas();
        datas.setName("Ahamed");
        datas.setDob(Calendar.getInstance());
        XStream stream = new XStream();
        System.out.println(stream.toXML(datas));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<Datas>
  <name>Ahamed</name>
  <dob>
    <time>1329081818801</time>
    <timezone>Asia/Calcutta</timezone>
  </dob>
</Datas>
```

I would like to format the dob tag without changing the getters and setters. Thanks.

Comment: Huge XML as in? Can we have an example?

Comment: Check out the [XStream - Converter Tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html). There's a section regarding date conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom converter for `Calendar` fields:

```
public class DateConverter implements Converter {

    private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        // This converter is only for Calendar fields.
        return Calendar.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
            MarshallingContext context) {
        Calendar calendar = (Calendar) value;
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        writer.setValue(formatter.format(date));
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
            UnmarshallingContext context) {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        try {
            calendar.setTime(formatter.parse(reader.getValue()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new ConversionException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return calendar;
    }
}
```

Register the above converter to XStream object as follows:

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.registerConverter(new DateConverter());
```

Now `xStream` object will look for Calendar fields and will marshall as defined in Custom Converter.

Comment: Be carefull with this: `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe. The easiest way to solve this is to construct a new SDF each time it is needed.

Answer (score 12):

An easy way is to register an (XStream!) DateConverter with the appropriate formats, e.g.:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.DateConverter;

XStream xstream = new XStream();
String dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
String timeFormat = "HHmmss";
String[] acceptableFormats = {timeFormat};
xstream.registerConverter(new DateConverter(dateFormat, acceptableFormats));
```

This works for me and I didn't need to create a new converter class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a custom converter in which under the marshal method modify your date format as you wish.
It should be done after DOB node.
I don't think you need to do anything in unmarshal method.
Good Luck :)